# Changing background color with a converter in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`TextBlock` background color not changing.

I've bound my data to a `TextBlock` which updates with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the converter does fire.

```
public class Oddsindicator : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string myPrice = "0";
        string tradePrice = "0";

        var colorRed = (System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFB0E0E6");
        var colorWhite = (System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("White");

        var unchanged = new SolidColorBrush(colorRed);
        var changed = new SolidColorBrush(colorGreen);

        if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            myPrice = values[0].ToString();
            tradePrice = values[1].ToString();
        }

        if (myPrice == tradePrice)
        {
            return unchanged;
        }
        else
        {
            return changed;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:Oddsindicator x:Key="Oddsindicator" >

    </local:Oddsindicator>

</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding BackPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Oddsindicator}">

            <Binding Path="BackPrice"/>
            <Binding Path="Lasttradedprice" />

        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.background>
</TextBlock>
```

I've used break points at the return and they both fire. My bound value updates perfectly. The converters comparing the values and giving the correct results, just not updating the `TextBlock`.

Comment: The converter always returns `new SolidColorBrush(colorRed)`. Your code is a mess. Why do you have the variables `unchanged`  and `changed` when you never use them? Besides that they are equal, which you certainly did not intend.

Comment: Sorry, I set to that to see if it was going to update the textblock, which it didnt. On start up the textblock stays white. It doesnt ever change to red, which it should do. I will edit the code. regerds robert

Comment: You have two TextBlocks. The second (for which you set the background) has no Text is is probably of 0 size.

Comment: Thank you, Im new to xaml, which are the two open elements. Is it the textblock text followed by textblock. Regards Robert

Answer (score 1):

(This should in fact be a comment but I need the formatting features of an answer)

You have two TextBlocks. The second (for which you set the background) has no Text and is probably of 0 size.
Try putting the `TextBlock.Background` in the first TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BackPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" >
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Oddsindicator}">
            <Binding Path="BackPrice"/>
            <Binding Path="Lasttradedprice" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Works perfect now. Will read a bit more about xaml layouts. This helps a lot. Regards Robert